# CSS Image Scaling without being Cropped

Tags: html, css

I have an image on the top page that's 960x200px wide. It's in a div tag. What happens is when I scale the page by pressing ctrl+scrolling, the image scales out of the page, off the screen, and gets cropped off. How can I make it that when I scale the page, like amazon.com or other websites, the page doesn't become cropped and instead, I get an horizontal scroll bar at bottom of the browser?

```
/* css */
#header { background-image: url('image.gif'); }

<!-- html -->
<div id="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your image is a `background-image`.

Therefore the width of the image is not being calculated as part of the width of the page.

If you want this not to happen, make your `div#header` explicitly 960px wide.

Comment: I see now that background-image is a background image that's why it didn't output the way I expected it to. After explicitly giving the #header div a width of 960px, it scaled smoothly. Thank you all for the helpful tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the header image part of the HTML code like this.

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="image.gif" width="960" height="200" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is HTML markup. <img> tag expects width and height to be expressed in pixels and any other value other than a pure numeric one (in case of using percent values the % sign is allowed) is considered to be illegal.